# How to get the front and rear elements of a cursor based list in a toString method?

Tags: java, arraylist, char

I have a ListADT which is a cursor based list of char. The toString method description is as follows:

> Gets a String representation of the state of this list. This String starts with a "<" and ends with a ">". In between are the elements of this list separated by commas, except that a pipe replaces the comma before the current element. There are no spaces after the "<", before the ">", nor around the commas nor the pipe. Examples of valid String representations are shown here: <a,g|c> <|>

My toString method looks like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {     
    
    String frmt = "<%S|%S>";
    String front = "";
    String rear = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize - 1; i++) {
        if (i == 0 && cur == 0) { front = "";}
        else {
            front = front.concat(",");
            front = front.concat(String.valueOf(elts[i])); 
        }         
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize - 1; i++) {
        if (cur >= listSize) { rear = "";}
        else {
            front = front.concat(",");
            rear = rear.concat(String.valueOf(elts[i]));
        }     
    }
    return String.format(frmt, front, rear);
    
}
```

For example:
When the list is currently "<|a,b,c>", front should equal "" and rear should equal "a,b,c".
When the list is currently "<a,b|c,d>", front should equal "a,b" and rear should equal "c,d".

However, this code when supposed to output "<|a,b,c>", instead output "<A,B,,|B>"

The goal is to create two different strings, front and rear, that represent the elements in the list before the cursor and the elements after the cursor. I can't seem to figure out how to do that so I was hoping for some help. I need something to be able to get all of those elements and comma separate them, then use the String.format to put it all together

Comment: Please describe in more detail what isn't working.  What does the current toString actually print.

Comment: @markspace that's the thing it doesn't. There's some sort of infinite loop or something and everything i've tried doesn't work. I just wanted to put my "thought process" here for what I was trying to do but by all means feel free to change anything

Comment: Can you step through with a debugger and find where it get stuck?  Add that info to the question.  And please say what the state of the object is, like "x strings, and the cursor is at y."

Answer (score 1):

I see one obvious problem:

```
    while (i < cur) {
        front = front.concat(String.valueOf(elts[i-1]));
    }
```

You never modify `i` or `cur` in this loop, so of course it gets stuck.  Same with the second `while` loop.

Comment: I added the changes you asked. Also I know I just don't know how to change that to make it so one of them is everything before the cursor and one is everything after

Comment: I may not even need the while loop I just didn't know what else to put

Comment: Removing the `while` loop will probably resolve the infinite loop.  You should just use the `front.concat(...` there and not the while.  You'll still have some debugging to do but at least you should get output.

Comment: Okay but the infinite loop isn't my biggest problem, how else can I so get the elements before cur and get the elements after cur. That's the main thing I'm trying to do

Comment: after removing the while loops, the expected outcome is "<|a,b,c>" but the actual outcome is "<A,B,,|B>" for some reason. I have no idea what to do

Comment: Update your question with that info, and update the code to the new version too.

Comment: Okay I just added the changes